# write and read csv file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode

I have a `text` file containing words with non-English alphabets and I want to open it, do some preprocess and finally save it as a `.csv` file, and use it some where else.

The code to read and store file:

```
with open('file.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    train = f.read().splitlines()
```

Then creating a dataframe, and the code to store it:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

util now every thing seems ok, but when I try to open the `file.csv` with this code:

```
train = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

I face this :

> Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

without going to next lines.

Also when I try to open it with ISO-8859-1 encoding, it is ok; but when I try to print the head of that `.csv` it just print some question marks(`'?'`)

Is anyone knows what is going wrong?

Comment: Might be a encoding issue. Any special characters in your source file?

Comment: as it is the text of some news, everything might be in it. also it is not in English.

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: it is in Persian

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing it with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('persian.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    train = f.read().splitlines() 
    df = pd.DataFrame({'text': train})
    df.to_csv('file.csv', index=True, encoding="utf-8")
    train = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

with a txt file containing two lines of sample Persian text. It ran without any problems in Python 3, producing this csv:

```
    text
0   همهٔ افراد بشر آزاد به دنیا می‌آیند و حیثیت و حقوق شان با هم برابر است
1   همه اندیشه و وجدان دارند و باید در برابر یکدیگر با روح برادری رفتار کنند.
```

Can you provide more detail on the text properties and the operations you did in the dataframe processing, or identify the line where the reading breaks? You might be producing some invalid characters on the way.

Comment: the process contains a simple split on each row of read data. also the file is about 1.5 Gig and I can't see what is the special character in it. Is there any way to ignore the errors based on special characters or another encoding which is consistent in front of them?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting crazy by writing Persian in a CSV file. Finally this one worked for me:

```
data.to_csv (r'hi.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```